# How to satisfy borrow checker with a value that is moved then immediately replaced in this unfold implementation?

Tags: rust

The following is an unsatisfying implementation of `unfold` because the closure must take `&A` instead of `A`.

```
pub fn unfold<A, B>(init: A, f: impl Fn(&A) -> Option<(A, B)>) -> impl Iterator<Item = B> {
      let mut acc = init;
      std::iter::from_fn(move || {
          f(&acc).map(|(a, b)| {
              acc = a;
              b
          })
      })
  }
```

If the `f` call returns `None`, the loop exits and `acc` is used no longer. If it returns `Some`, `acc` is replaced with a new value.

Any way to have `f` take `A` instead of `&A` without unsafe, or `Copy` or other requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Having `f` take `A` directly is not possible because if `f` panics, `acc` could be left in an undefined state.

A simple way to fix this is to make `acc` an `Option<A>`.

```rust
pub fn unfold2<A, B>(init: A, f: impl Fn(A) -> Option<(A, B)>) -> impl Iterator<Item = B> {
    let mut acc = Some(init);
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        // The unwrap below is okay because `acc` being None means the iterator is over.
        // The iterator API says that calling `next` on spent iterator can panic.
        f(acc.take().unwrap()).map(|(a, b)| {
            acc = Some(a);
            b
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: If `f` panics, all bets are off anyway ...

Comment: @Ana Normally that's what we want, yes. But for the compiler things are more complicated. When `f` panics, the panicking mechanism still needs to drop all the values before the program ends. This includes calling `Drop::drop(&mut acc)`. This requires that `acc` be valid.